# R `as` method for converting custom S4 class

Tags: r, type-conversion, package, r-s4, coercion

I'm developing an R package and want to include a function that overrides `igraph::as.igraph()` and lets users convert my custom class into an `igraph::igraph` object. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the generic from the igraph package, and export your method for your class.

```r
#' @importFrom igraph as.igraph
NULL

#' @export
as.igraph.yourclass <- function(x, ...)
{
    your code here
}
```

Comment: I can get `as.igraph.yourclass` to work but I still get this error when I just use `as.igraph`: `Error in UseMethod("as.igraph") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.igraph' applied to an object of class "network"`

Comment: Redocument your package

Comment: Success! Thank you